# Что значит эта ошибка и как ее исправить? setValue:forUndefinedKey:

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

`2016-12-14 23:17:04.949 TestProject[15212:17645799] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TestProject.ViewController 0x7fc224609360> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f53234b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c93221e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f532299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c44226f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010cf9b4ef -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d20f79e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4d7590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d20e122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010cfa1c21 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010cfa2543 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010cfa2878 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010cfa30cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ce6cc51 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010ce6d3a2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ce80cb5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010cdf9c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010cdffde9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010cdfcf69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110bf6723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110bf659c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110bf6925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4d7311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4bc59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4bba86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4bb494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010cdfb7e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010ce01964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  TestProject                         0x000000010c3530ef main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011045f68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

Возникает сразу при попытке запуска симулятора[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ошибка снизу справа в консоли. скопируйте весь текст и добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko добавил!

Comment: Проверьте theLabel, она не соединена с Вашим кодом

Answer (score 1):

В коде (в частности ViewController.swift) переменная называется `theLabel1`, а в строиброде связь написана к переменной `theLabel`.

Либо прееименуйте переменную обратно, либо сделайте новую связь из storyboard

Comment: Попробовал, но что-то не помогает

Comment: может быть еще в чем-то проблема?

Comment: может еще есть смысл clean rebuild сделать. если хотите дайте ссылку на проект, так быстрее будет посмотреть

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/cPQdTRz733dt6s

Comment: исправил ответ @Goncharoff